# Using @computedFrom with a FileList in Aurelia

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I'm having an issue with the values not updating when they are updated in the view.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Files</label>
    <input type="file" multiple files.bind="fileList" class="form-control" />
</div>

<tr repeat.for="projectDocument of projectDocumentItems">
    <td>
        <input type="text" value.bind="projectDocument.file.name" class="form-control" />
    </td>
    <td>${projectDocument.file.size}</td>
    <td>${projectDocument.file.type}</td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" value.bind="projectDocument.test" />
        <select class="form-control" value.bind="projectDocument.projectFileType">
            <option>Select a Document Type</option>
            <option repeat.for="documentType of documentTypes" model.bind="documentType">${documentType.name}</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

---

```
import {computedFrom} from "aurelia-framework"
import {autoinject} from "aurelia-dependency-injection"

@autoinject
export class AddDocument {
    project = {};
    fileList: FileList;
    documentTypes = [
        { id: 1, name: "Blueprint" },
        { id: 2, name: "Shop Drawing" },
        { id: 3, name: "Proposal" },
        { id: 4, name: "Signed Proposal" }];

    constructor() {
    }

    @computedFrom("fileList")
    get projectDocumentItems(): ProjectDocumentItem[] {
        let files = [];
        if (!this.fileList) {
            return files;
        }

        for (let i = 0; i < this.fileList.length; i++) {
            let projectDocumentItem = new ProjectDocumentItem(this.fileList.item(i));
            projectDocumentItem.projectFileType = this.documentTypes[2];
            files.push(projectDocumentItem);
        }

        return files;
    }

    activate(params, routeConfig, navigationInstruction) {
        this.project = { Id: params.id };
    }

    upload() {
        console.log(this.projectDocumentItems);
    }

}

class ProjectDocumentItem {
    constructor(private file: File) {
    }

    test: string;

    projectFileType: {};
}
```

I set up a test property for the project document called test that I was using to test binding. Not shown is a upload input that will accept multiple files and binds to the fileList property.

The projectDocumentItems getter is computed and creates a bunch of ProjectDocumentItems which include the test and projectFileType properties. I set a default projectFileType and the correct dropdown value is displayed in the form, but when I change it and view the projectDocumentItems property values, the old value is still there.

Edit:
To be clear, the fileList property is being observed correctly and if I select multiple documents I get multiple ProjectDocumentItems to loop through. The issue is, the ProjectDocumentItem properties are not being observed when a change is made.

The flow of the form is as follows:

1. The user selects one or more files to be uploaded.
2. The fileList property changes.
3. The projectDocumentItems getter is computed.
4. projectDocumentItems loops through the File objects in the fileList property and creates new ProjectDocumentItems and returns an array of them.
5. The view is updated listing the ProjectDocumentItems that have been created with the correct values of the file properties and the value of the documentType property correctly selected in the dropdown.
6. Issue: The problem is, if I change the dropdown and select another document type or if I type something into the textbox which is bound to ProjectDocumentItem.test, the value isn't bound back to that ProjectDocumentItem in the collection.

Comment: why compute the project document items?

Comment: The alternative would be adding the properties to each file in the File List object. I'm open to other ways to accomplish the task, I just wasn't sure if I was doing something wrong or if I had ran into a bug to report.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `@computedFrom` can't listen to arrays. Try the following instead.

```
import { BindingEngine } from "aurelia-framework"
import { autoinject } from "aurelia-dependency-injection"

@autoinject
export class AddDocument {
    project = {};
    fileList: FileList;
    projectDocumentItems: ProjectDocumentItems[];

    subscriptions = [];

    documentTypes = [
        { id: 1, name: "Blueprint" },
        { id: 2, name: "Shop Drawing" },
        { id: 3, name: "Proposal" },
        { id: 4, name: "Signed Proposal" }];

    constructor(BindingEngine) {
        this.binding = BindingEngine;
    }

    activate(params, routeConfig, navigationInstruction) {
        this.project = { Id: params.id };
        this.projectDocumentItems = [];

        this.subscriptions.push(
            bindingEngine.collectionObserver(this.fileList)
                .subscribe((items) => 
                    items.forEach((item) => {
                        let projectDocumentItem = new ProjectDocumentItem(item);
                        projectDocumentItem.projectFileType = this.documentTypes[2];
                        this.projectDocumentItems.push(projectDocumentItem);
                    })
                )
        );
    }

    deactivate() {
        this.subscriptions.forEach((subscription) => subscription.dispose());
    }
}
```

There may be some issues with the definition of `items` and `item`, so double check that. Documentation available here: http://aurelia.io/docs.html#/aurelia/binding/1.0.0-beta.1.1.3/doc/api/interface/CollectionObserver

Comment: docs link is for future reading, when that area of the docs gets generated

Comment: Does the line "bindingEngine.collectionObserver(this.list)" reference this.fileList? If that is the case, the typescript definition is throwing an error due to FileList not being an array.

Comment: I think I didn't describe my issue well in my question. The observing fileList works just fine since it is just an object and not an array... I'm not sure why they chose to implement FileList that way, but I'm really not strong in JavaScript... I'll try to clarify my question to better explain my issue.

Comment: I appended the original question to clarify the issue. Thanks for your help!